# Magento 2 - Is it safe to remove the DEFINER=.. statement from sqldump?

Tags: magento2, database, aws

I have a web server that serves Magento2 and a MySQL Server that hosts the database and both of these servers are in a single ubuntu instance.

I would like to move the MySQL server to a separate RDS MySQL instance, so I have dumped the database with mysqldump as root user and while uploading it to RDS MySQL instance I get:

`"ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 2873: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation"`

I have checked for the solution and removed DEFINER with `sed 's/\sDEFINER=`[^`]*`@`[^`]*`//g' -i dumpedfile.sql` and after removing DEFINER the upload worked without any error.

My question is, what exactly definer is, is it safe to remove it from the dumped file of a Magento 2 database?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't precisely a Magento question, but I think [Google answers your question](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/preparing-your-mysql-database-migration-database-migration-service) in a slightly different context. I'd work on synchronizing users between database instances before migration rather than simply remove that value:

> **DEFINER clause**
>
> Because a MySQL migration job doesn't migrate user data, sources that
> contain metadata defined by users with the DEFINER clause will fail
> when invoked on the new Cloud SQL replica, as the users don't yet
> exist there.
>
> You can identify which `DEFINER` values exist in your metadata by using
> these queries. Check if there are entries for either `root%localhost` or
> users that don't exist in the target instance.
>
> `SELECT DISTINCT DEFINER FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS;`
>
> `SELECT DISTINCT DEFINER FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES;`
>
> `SELECT DISTINCT DEFINER FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS;`
>
> `SELECT DISTINCT DEFINER FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS;`
>
> If your source database does contain this metadata you can do one of
> the following:
>
> Update the `DEFINER` clause to `INVOKER` on your source MySQL instance
> prior to setting up your migration job. Create the users on your
> target Cloud SQL instance before starting your migration job. Create a
> migration job without starting it. That is, choose Create instead of
> Create & Start.
>
> Create the users from your source MySQL instance on your target Cloud
> SQL instance using the Cloud SQL API or UI.
>
> Start the migration job from the migration job list or the specific
> job's page.